# Using the browser client, how can I set the sounds.disconnect() on every call?

Tags: browser, client, twilio, audio

Using the browser client, how can I set the sounds.disconnect() on every call? Is there a way to access the device singleton to modify that setting? I know I can access when I get the device.ready callback, but I want to modify the setting on every call.

Answer (score 0):

I received a helpful reply back from Twilio support:

--

That parameter will be instantiated in Twilio.Device either True or False once the web page loads, so to change it, I believe you would necessarily need to also reload the page.

This would create another control layer in effect, that isn't provided out of the box by Twilio: you'd need to build a web page to change the variable that determines sounds.outgoing(), and then trigger the page to reload.

Another option would be simply create a second Client instance running on a separate tab, and have both instances use the same outbound caller ID. That might be easier.

--

In my scenario I'll need to find a different approach, and will look in to disabling the Twilio sounds and using my own.